# How to express the size of an intersection of a combination of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set of sets $s \in S$. I would like to return true if I have an intersection between $n$ of the sets in $S$.

The closest thing I can come up with is $\bigcap^n_{i=0} s^i \neq \emptyset$, but this is iterating over the first $n$ $s \in S$, and what I really want to say is that if $\textit{any}$ combination of $s$ of size $n$ intersect, then return true.

How would I express this?

Comment: Wait, I am confused ... in your title you indicate to want to express the size of some intersection .. But now you just want to see if there are $n$ sets in $S$ whose intersection is not empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

$$\exists C: \; C \subset S \; \land \;|C| = n \;\land \;\bigcap_{s \in C} s \not = \emptyset$$

which may even work for $n$ an infinite cardinal